# Using dimensions with arrays in dc.js for treemap

Tags: javascript, dc.js, treemap, crossfilter

Since crossfilter (1.4.0-alpha.6) allows use array as a dimension value, is it possible to use it for treemap viz for a nested tree? https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/pull/1034 It works perfectly for one value, but what if I want more. It seems that approach that was used for dc.js treemap example can't work with the new feature of crossfilter.

I have a data structure with a couple of multiple values so I can't unwind them due to performance.

Now I'm thinking to create 2 treemaps for 2 different array dimensions, and after selecting the key on first, hide it and show the second treemap... Maybe, guys, you have much better ideas?

Comment: I hate to ask, but does this actually make sense? With tag / array dimensions they add up to more than 100% because each row contributes to multiple categories. But a tree map is supposed to show how hierarchical categories add up to 100%.